# Using Datastore (from GCP) as a backend result for Celery in python

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-firestore, celery, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently trying to implement a task queue (for running background tasks) using RabbitMQ as a broker and Datastore in gcp as a result backend. The whole is managed by Celery. This latter takes into account several backend implementation such as mongodb, CouchDB etc (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#rpc-backend-settings)

ex : `celery_app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://localhost:5672', backend='mongodb://localhost:27017')`

but not datastore from gcp or even any gcp products.

Should I develop the library on my own or does anyone already dealt with celery and google database product and found a quicker solution ?

Otherwise, is there any way to have an endpoint url for datastore database in gcp so that I can add it in celery config backend as below ?

`celery_app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://localhost:5672', backend=DATASTORE_URL)`

Hope that I've been clear enough.

Thanks in advance !